# Rerun a code until you get a specific output

Tags: python, loops, random, equation

I want to run a script that could make any math equation true (well not any but some), and say I wanted to solve this math equation `a + b = c`. I generated numbers for A and B and C until it generates the right numbers say `1 + 2 = 3`. How would I do this?

```
import random 

numberA = random.randrange(50,100) #the range doesn't matter it could be whatever
numberB = random.randrange(50,100)
numberC = random.randrange(50,100)

if numberA + numberB = numberC:
  print "Your equation is now true because %s + %s = %s" % (numberA, numberB, numberC) 
else:
  print "Error, retrying..."
```

Is there any possible way for me to get Python to just instantly rerun this code until one comes out true and ends up printing the "Your equation is true..." statement without having to copy/paste the code then hit enter and hope it generates the right numbers on that one.

I cannot figure out how to do it with a while loop (then again I am not that good with while loops) so is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
import random 

while True:
    numberA = random.randrange(50,100)
    numberB = random.randrange(50,100)
    numberC = random.randrange(50,100)
    if numberA + numberB == numberC: break
    print "Error, retrying..." 
print "Your equation is now true because %s + %s = %s" % (numberA, numberB, numberC)
```

FYI If you have a more complicated equation, it may take a very long time to find a solution randomly. If there is no solution, the code like above would run indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can wrap everything in a `while True:` loop:

```
import random 

while True:
  numberA = random.randrange(50, 101)
  numberB = random.randrange(50, 101)
  numberC = random.randrange(50, 101)
  if numberC == numberA + numberB:
    print 'Your equation is now true: C = %s, A = %s, B = %s' %(numberC, numberA, numberB)
    break
```

Note: In the example you posted with all variables being equal to `random.randrange(50, 100)` `numberC` will never be equal to `numberA` + `numberB` because the range does not include 100 but stops at 99. You can either increase the range with 1 like showed in my example or you can replace with `random.randint(50, 100)`.
In either case there is only one possible solution:

```
Your equation is now true: C = 100, A = 50, B = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this:

```
x, y = 50, 100
for a, b, c in product(range(x, y), range(x, y), range(x, y)):
    if equation(a, b, c):
        print("Success!")
        break 
else:
    print("Can't be solved.")
```

This works through in order, rather than randomly jumping around, so will go to the `else` case if no numbers in `range(x, y)` fit the `equation`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random
flag=False
while(flag==False):
    numberA = random.randrange(1,2)
    numberB = random.randrange(1,2)
    numberC = random.randrange(1,3)
    if (numberA+numberB == numberC):
        print str(numberA)+" "+str(numberB)+" "+str(numberC)
        flag=True
    else:
        print "error"
```

Comment: First, it should be `while not flag`. Second, using a `flag` like this (rather than `break`) is not pythonic.

Comment: oh really! Pythonic :P